# Web service security in SOAP

Tags: security, web, service

Why does the SOAP protocol introduce the notion of XML encryption and digital signatures (to guarantee the confidentiality and the integrity of the data being exchanged between the client and the server), when everything about the security (integrity, confidentiality and authentication) can be guaranteed by simply using the HTTPS protocol?

Comment: HTTPS only guarantees them when it's end-to-end. You can have intermediaries in more complex SOAP setups e.g. an ESB

Comment: But why don't use https protocol between intermediaries ? I would like to know why does SOAP opt for the XML Encryption and Digital Signature between the intermediaries whereas we can use of https instead ? Another question , why SOAP protocol is known as more secure than REST protocol although with REST we can use **https**  as a secure transport layer that guarantees confidentiality, integrity and authentication ?

Comment: the endpoints don't have to trust the intermediary if you sign and encrypt the message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primarily because SOAP is a protocol that can be used over other transportation protocols ([TCP/named pipes/MSMQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649712.aspx)) than https. These do not offer the same protection as https does.

Also, as @artbristol pointed out, https protects a message between two endpoints. See Vitorrio Bertocci's [article here](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2005/04/25/end-to-end-security-or-why-you-shouldn-t-drive-your-motorcycle-naked/) for more info. Sure, you can use https between all endpoints, but the machine doing the decryption and encryption has access to the cleartext (which it may log in the web server logs for example).